# PageLoad Event Is Not Fired When An Aspx Is Opened Through Jquery Of ascx anchor tag

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a anchor tag like this

```
<a href="" class="search gl">
    <img src="_gfx/cmn/goButton.png" class="searchbutton" name="btn"></img>
</a>
```

Button from jquery I am setting this href based on different conditions to different page.

```
$(".search gl").attr("href", "test.aspx");
```

But when I click on that anchor its loading the test.aspx page but not hitting the page_load event.I have to add some more conditions in that page load. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the page is loaded but the event is not hit probably you have missed to specify the handler for the page load.

if in your page you got  `AutoEventWireup="true"`

- remove the handler
- swithc to design
- double click anywhere on the page

it will add the handler in the Page.aspx.Designer

otherwise you have to do it manually

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            this.Load += page_load;
        }
```

Comment: When I create an aspx page it will automatically create the event for page_load right?

Comment: that's right but it can happen it has lost the handler.
just to make sure this is the issue try to set AutoWireUp=false and add the code above for adding the hanlred in the page init(which is the best practice anyway)

Comment: It seems like the solution, I will try and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** have spaces in your class name:

Try:

```
<a href="" class="search_gl">
```

Then:

```
$(".search_gl").something(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that code inside `$(document).ready()` or `$()` and change the selector to `.search.gl`.

```
$(function(){
   $(".search.gl").attr("href", "test.aspx");
});
```

If you want to use this link to post back to the same page then why do you are you setting `href`?

Comment: It's loading the page "test.aspx" properly if I use $(".searcg gl") also,but not firing the page_load event of "test.aspx" page.

Comment: Do you have any event handler attached to anchor or image element?